# Wizard of Legend controller support on Amazon Games

Tags: controllers, wizard-of-legend

I've heard that Wizard of Legend has controller support, for example through big picture mode in Steam. I have the game through Amazon Games and I can't get the controllers to work. Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you go on Steam, use big picture mode, and go into settings, you can configure controller settings. Check the relevant controller types/drivers you want. To get the game to show up in your library, go to the Games dropdown menu and click "Add a Non-Steam Game to My Library," then browse to the relevant folder (in this case C:\Amazon Games\Library\Wizard of Legend) and select the .exe file. Running the game from big picture mode should work with the controllers.